# Amazon S3 response does not return date header

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, response-headers

I've written a js SDK that fetches a static file from S3:

```
fetch(new Request("https://url.to.my.S3.file.js")).then((response) => {
    //logging the response headers
    response.headers.forEach((val,key)=>{
         console.log(key,' = ',val)})
})
```

When logging the headers I only get

```
content-type   =  application/javascript
last-modified  =  Mon, 22 Oct 2018 08:00:35 GMT
```

I'm missing the date header, which is available on my local server.
How can I configure my S3 bucket so date header will be available?

Comment: Can you give an actual working URL?

Comment: Sorry, I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was I was trying to get the resource from a different domain. I did add the `<CORSConfiguration>` to my S3 bucket but was missing the `<ExposeHeader>` node.

After adding it, as [seen here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html), all worked fine.